# Excel 2010 - In cell text appending

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, editing

Let's say I have a text called 'Boy' in cell A1. Now if I have to append the letter 's' at the end, I have to either click the formula bar and add 's' at the end or press F2 to go to edit mode and then add it. Is there any way or any add-in which allows me to simply append value to a cell which already has some text in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CONCATENATE` formula, or something like `=A1 & "s"`.

You already explained the other manual ways. Another way would be to use a macro in combination with an user-input or user-input-form.

It could work like this:

- select the range/cell, where appening should happen
- excecute macro through e.g. shortkey
- dialog pops up to aks for text to append
- type text
- execute appending

Another way might be using the search/replace functionality.

*Edit*

Although I find this a strange way to type in data, and would not rant against MS in this point - here is a somewhat solution to this refined behavior:

```
'VBA code for Sheet1

Private var As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  On Error Resume Next
  If state Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    var = var & Target.Formula
    Target.Formula = var
    Debug.Print var
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If state Then
    var = Target.Formula
    Debug.Print var
  End If
End Sub

'VBA Code for Module1

Public state As Boolean

Public Sub switchState()
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  state = Not state
  Debug.Print state
End Sub
```

Comment: But I don't want to use any of these. I just want to start typing and text should append at the end. I have searched a lot, couldn't find any solution :-(.. Microsoft is so stupid not to provide this option!

Comment: ok, so you want to select a random cell, and then, just by typing in values it should append them. And I would guess there should somewhere be an option to activate/deativate this behaviour right?

Comment: yes, if it is available kindly let me know.. or at least is there anyway to change the shortcut key F2 to F6? I am asking this for a very important reason. I use a Dell Studio 1555 and the laptop has a mind of its own. I set the function keys behavior to Function key first, but after couple of days, it resets back to multimedia keys first. since my F6 key is empty, I thought of assigning the key to Edit mode

Comment: wow, thats a lot of code.. can you guide me what to do with this code?

Comment: @thandasoru - see my edit. I don't really like this solution, but it kinda does what you want. Would not lable MS stupid because they did not provide this, this is quite an confusing behavior.

Comment: Trust me, I need such an option, as I edit lot of German words. German words are really big and it is time consuming typing the whole word or doing F2 to append text..

Comment: thats a tiny bit of code - you haven't seen a lot yet ^^ - you would just need to paste it, where I said to paste it. One part to the code-section of your sheet - the other as the code of a module, which you most likely have to insert first.

Comment: haha - look @ my profile ;) - got to go now - sry.

Comment: Sind Sie Deutsch? Sie können mein problem verstanden :-)